# How to find minimum from a set of minimums in a query?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a query which looks something like :

```
Select min(x) from A
UNION 
Select min(x) from B
UNION
Select min(x) from C 
.
.
.
Select min(x) from Z
```

Now , i want to return the minimum of these values using a SELECT statement.
Is it possible , considering i'm using DB2 as my database?

P.S. : I'm aware that i can insert the output of the above in temp table and get the min from there. But the Insert operation is costly , since most of these have > 1BN rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using a nested `SELECT`:

```
SELECT MIN(V) FROM (
    Select min(x) AS V from A
    UNION 
    Select min(x) AS V from B
    UNION
    Select min(x) AS V from C 
    .
    .
    .
    Select min(x) AS V from Z
) t
```

Since you are applying an aggregate function to the values, you may as well replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.